# package R does not exist after renaming app

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio

I imported project that I bought and it runs fine in Android Studio and on my mobile.

Did some minor layout modifications and Build-Generate Signed APK..." All went fine there. When I try to upload APK to Google Play i get this error message

```
You need to use a different package name because "com.projects.myprojectname" already exists in Google Play.
```

Then I changed the name in AndroidManifest.xml - package:com.xpodspofs.xpospor" to be sure that the name does not exist.

After that I got 101 errors:

```
"error: package R does not exist"
```

Comment: is there any error in layout files..??

Comment: R file is automatically generated if there's no error in your code. Try to see if package name is changed everywhere and there's no error left.

Comment: It has not changed everywhere just in manifest (manually), everywhere else is same. I tried opening each error and changed the name but that lead to another 101 errors but this time they are not about package R.

Comment: @saurabh. no errors in layout files as i can build APK without changing the name with no errors at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to completely rebuild your Project with `Build -> Clean Project` and then `Build -> Rebuild Project`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project, and manually copy-paste all the classes, xml files and the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your build.gradle file, and after correcting it and manifest file, restart android studio and then rebuild project.